# How to tell if the following function is one to one

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

Let f:A→B where A = X∪Y with X∩Y=∅. If f|x and f|y are one-to-one, does it follow that f is one-to-one?

I am unsure how to figure this out. I have gathered from the info provided that X and Y are different sets with no shared elements, meaning A is the set of everything in X and everything in Y, without any elements repeating.

Where do I go from here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HINT: Is there anything in the hypothesis to prevent the existence of an $x\in X$ and a $y\in Y$ such that $f(x)=f(y)$? If not, can you find an actual example of this phenomenon?

Comment: I think that X∩Y=∅ prevents f(x) = f(y), which would make the function 1 to 1. Would that be correct?

Unless for example the function was x^2 and X = {1,2,3) and Y= {-1, -2, -3}. In that case the function would not be one to one?

Comment: The function is not 1-1.

Comment: @user3362196: The second part of your comment is correct: in that example $f$ is not one-to-one. And that example shows that the hypotheses that you were given do **not** imply that $f$ is one-to-one (though of course you can also find examples in which it is).